# TestNG skipping @Test, when dependent tests are marked as Pass

Tags: java, testng

Here's my scenario:

In many of my tests, I may throw a `PassedException` (An exception I created that says that the test passed, but to stop the execution).

Originally, all of my tests had a `expectedExceptions = PassedException.class`, and threw a `PassedException` at the very end.  I didn't like this solution.

I changed it so that in my `TestListener`, in the method `onTestFailure(ITestResult result)`, I check to see the throwable type is `PassedException.class`, and if it is, call `result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS)`.

This works...the tests are marked as passes, however, if another test depends on a method that  threw a `PassedException.class`, then it will skip it.

Do any of you know why this is the case, and how to fix it (or a workaround)?

EDIT: Here is a duplicable case:

```
public class PassedException extends RuntimeException{}

public class Tester {

 @Test
 public static void test1(){
    throw new PassedException(); 
 }
 @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
 public static void test2(){

 }
}

public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result){
    Throwable t = result.getThrowable();
    if (t.getClass().equals(PassedException.class)){
        result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Not answering the question, but abusing exceptions in this way will most likely hunt you again in the future. Why do you want to skip parts of a test in the first place? Why can't you use a simple `return` in the test method, if you absolutely have to cancel a running test?

Comment: @Pyranja I have an Assertion class that has the ability to pass/fail based on the user.  So, if I'm logged in as a basic user, this awesome power button shouldn't be available, and so the assertion should fail correctly...but since I can't continue, "failing correctly" means throwing a PassedException.

Comment: No, I never did.  I emailed the developer several times, and he never got back to me.  I ended up refactoring the tests.

Comment: Ok! But even soft dependency is not a good idea. It would run even if the failure is a legitimate one

Comment: You're right.  We ended up scrapping PassedException and going a different route because of this issue.

Comment: @NathanMerrill This has been fixed in the latest versions of testng !

Answer (score 2):

I admit, that I do not fully understand the reasoning behind the PassingException, but I have two suggestions:

- The workaround

  @Test(alwaysRun = true, dependsOnMethods = { "myFailingTest" })

This creates a *soft dependency*, i.e. the annotated test should be executed even if the tests it depends on failed/threw an exception ([documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods)). But that you encounter such a problem in the first case, indicates that there is either a bug in TestNG or your test design conflicts with the intended usage of TestNG. Using this workaround will imho hurt you in the long run.

- Refactoring the tests

Using the `expectedExceptions` option is a sound approach to test fail-fast scenarios in an application. As far as I understand your use case, the key would be to narrow your tests in such a way, that there is just one possible outcome, i.e. in the given example you would have a test that emulates a "super user", where the *awesome power button* is available and does something awesome, which you assert. Then there is another test - emulating a "simple user" - where it is not available and you always expect a `PassingException` to be thrown.

Comment: Option 2 is not feasible.  We've got 8 different users, and lots of tests.  However, the soft dependency isn't a bad idea...do you know if it is possible auto-add alwaysRun=true in a listener by looking at the tests that it depended upon?

Comment: sorry but my knowledge of TestNG is rather limited.

Comment: Note that `dependsOn` is now `dependsOnMethods`